# Left-elements of a numerical semigroup generated by two elements

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, semigroups-and-monoids

A numerical semigroup $S$ is a semigroup in $\mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathbb{N}\backslash S$ is finite. It is known that there exists always a set $M$ such that an element in $S$ can be expressed as a finite sum of elements in $M$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{N}$. For example $S=\mathbb{N}\backslash\{1\}$ is the numerical semigroup generated by $2$ and $3$, and in such a case we write $S=\langle 2,3\rangle$. We define the following:

- $F(S)=\max\{\mathbb{N}\backslash S\}$ is the Frobenius number of $S$;
- $N(S)=\{s\in S: s<F(S)\}$ is the set of the left-elements of $S$;
- $n(S)$ is the cardinality of $N(S)$.

Consider a semigroup $T=\langle m,n\rangle$, with $\gcd(m,n)=1$.
I would like to ask kindly if someone knows some references (as recent articles) in which the authors study the elements in $N(T)$ (not $n(T)$) in according to the generators $m$ and $n$ of $T$.

For example, if we consider the numeric semigroup $ S = \langle 2,3\rangle $, then we can say that $ S = \mathbb {N} \backslash \{1 \} $, so $ F (S) = 1 $ and consequently $ N (S) = \{0 \} $ trivially. Complicatingly, we consider two-dimensional numeric semigroups, where $ m = 2 $ and $ n $ is any odd, other than $ 3 $. Just to fix ideas for example $ m = 2 $ and $ n = 7 $. Then $ S = \mathbb {N} \backslash \{1,3,5 \} $, so $ F (S) = 5 $ and consequently $ N (S) = \{0,2,4 \} $ . In general, if $ n $ is any odd, it is easy to observe that $ N (S) $ is made up of all evens that are less than $ F (S) = n-3 $ (it being known that, if $ S = \langle a, b\rangle $, then $ F (S) = ab-a-b-1 $ and $ n (S) = \frac {(a-1)(b-1)}{2} $).

I would like to kindly ask you if there are any references in the literature on the study of $ N (T) $, where $ T $ is a numeric semigroup generated by any $ m $ and $ n $. That is to say, once we have given $ T = \langle m, n\rangle $ a "something" has been found that allows us to identify elements smaller than $ F (S) $ known the generators $ m $ a $ n $ ?? ?

Comment: Cross posted  as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4393162/left-elements-of-a-numerical-semigroup-generated-by-two-elements

Comment: I suppose it bears saying that $F(T) = mn - (m+n)$ in this case. So this is always an upper bound on $n(T)$.

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda but it seems the OP wants a description of N(T) rather than n(T). I've seen on Google some papers on the latter but not on the former.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Yes, sure, but a weak upper bound on $n(T)$ is a very mild bit of known information about $N(T)$, too (it’s not that I’m answering their question, just adding some background info).

Comment: Don't know if this is of any use to you, but $$ \sum_{k\in S} x^k = \frac{1-x^{mn}}{(1-x^m)(1-x^n)}. $$

Comment: The standard name for the elements of the natural numbers that are NOT in the numerical semigroup T is the set of gaps.  By ``left-elements'' do you mean the gaps???   It would help to use standard notation.  Assuming this is what you mean.. there is a lot known.  GAP has a library built by authors of a book on Numerical Semigroups that will compute the gaps.  For semigroups like your <n, m> with n, m relatively prime -- and more generallly the semigroups of plane curve singularities, the elements of the Gap are exactly half the conductor. The conductor is 1 plus the Frobenius element.